# connecting amazon redshift server from tableau server

Tags: tableau-api, amazon-redshift

I have installed Tableau server in my PC. I am trying to connect Amazon Redshift server from tableau server directly like connecting redshift from tableau desktop. I am not found any options for it. Is it possible? and i am using tableau server trail version. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tableau Server is used to store published data connections and workbooks created in Tableau Desktop. Whilst it is possible to edit an existing data connections, it is not possible to create a brand-new data connection on Tableau Server.

When publishing a workbook or data connection that uses Amazon Redshift, make sure that the appropriate driver is installed on the Tableau Server machine ([Tableau Support drivers page](http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers))

Comment: what are the drivers i have to install  in tableau server machine to connect amazon redshift server?

Comment: Go to this page http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers and download the Amazon Redshift driver (essentially a postgreSQL driver) and you should be good to go.